# NodeJS put array in MongoDB doc.validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to push array of objects into MongoDB through NodeJS.

So my schema

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    added: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    displayName: String,
    login: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    password: String,
    salt: String,
    role: Number,
    hasPremium: Boolean,
    avatar: Buffer,
    description: String,
    additional: [{
        name: String,
        data: String
    }],
    cart: [{
        exposition: Object,
        offer: Object,
        state: Number,
        history: [{
            date: Date,
            state: Number,
            modifier: Number
        }]
    }],
    balance: Number,
    topUps: [{
        orderNumber: String,
        sum: Number,
        added: Date,
        paid: Date
    }],
    lock: Boolean
});
```

My save controller

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function (req, username, password, done) {
            findOrCreateUser = function () {
                // find a user in Mongo with provided username
                UserModel.findOne({'login': username}, function (err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error in SignUp: ' + err);
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    // already exists
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('User already exists with username: ' + username);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Already Exists'));
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user with that email
                        // create the user
                        var newUser = new UserModel();
                        // set the user's local credentials
                        newUser.displayName = req.param('displayName');
                        newUser.login = username;
                        newUser.password = createHash(password);
                        newUser.email = req.param('email');
                        newUser.phone = req.param('phone');
                        newUser.role = req.param('role');
                        newUser.description = req.param('description');
                        if (req.param('avatar')) {
                            var avatar = new Buffer(req.param('avatar')).toString('base64');
                            newUser.avatar = new Buffer(avatar, 'base64');
                        }
                        var adds = req.param('additional');
                        console.log(adds);
                        if (adds) {
                            newUser.additional = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < adds.length; i++) {
                                newUser.additional[i] = {};
                                newUser.additional[i].name = adds[i].name;
                                newUser.additional[i].data = adds[i].data;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(newUser.additional);
                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Error in Saving user: ' + err);
                                throw err;
                            }
                            console.log('User Registration succesful');
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
            // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
            // in the next tick of the event loop
            process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
        })
    );

    // Generates hash using bCrypt
    var createHash = function (password) {
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    }
}
```

So, when I run this code I got strange error

```
TypeError: doc.validate is not a function
```

Even if I had no validation in my scheme.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Show your full controller/model definition, not part

Comment: It works when I remove this part from my code, so I am sure, that problem is there.

Comment: If you want an answer that would help you, post full code that has problem context, not part of it, for now for example i dont know what is `done` function, what is `req.param` in your context, etc.

Comment: req.param is params from my angular controller anyway, updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Check the `req.param('additional');`, maybe you could remove redundant conversion via for loop

Comment: No, objects are clear. I have printed to console both objects(adds and user.additional) and both have identical data: [ { name: 'TestName', data: 'TestData' },
  { name: 'TestName1', data: 'TestData1' } ]

Comment: Then why would you use for loop? `newUser.additional = req.param('additional');`

Comment: I really don't know when and why I came to this decision. Ofc there was something that I wanted to check or maybe it didn't work this way in other reasons. Anyway, thank you very much Medet. Привет из Алматы! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I don't know what happened but when I did it like

```
newUser.additional = req.param('additional');
```

Insted of this part of code

```
if (adds) {
    newUser.additional = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < adds.length; i++) {
        newUser.additional[i] = {};
        newUser.additional[i].name = adds[i].name;
        newUser.additional[i].data = adds[i].data;
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly. There is still magic for me...